# Slow postgres query that uses quick sort instead of hash-aggregate

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, group-by, query-performance

I'm on Postgres 9.5 and working with a web analytics database that records visitor traffic.

I'm trying to optimize a very slow query that gives me a count of the unique people that visited a given page grouped by their session device type.

The query looks like so:

```
select   groupname,  count(person_id) as thecount
from (
  select distinct S.first_device_type as groupname, A.person_id
  from event_page as O
  join alias as A
    on (O.person_alias = A.alias)
  left outer join session as S
    on (O.session_id = S.session_id) 
  join alias as A1
    on ( A1.alias = S.person_alias and A.person_id = A1.person_id)
  where O.timestamp_ between timestamp '2017-02-11 23:22:20.146' and timestamp '2017-03-13 23:22:20.146'
    and O.location_host = 'www.foo.bar.ca'
    and S.first_seen between timestamp '2017-02-11 23:22:20.146' and timestamp '2017-03-13 23:22:20.146'
) as alias_120134400
group by groupname
```

The above SQL runs in over 2.5 minutes and the output looks like this.

```
device type        count
--------------------------
Computer       |  163304
Game console   |      41
Mobile         |   33519
Tablet         |   10465
Unknown        |       5
```

There are a couple of peculiarities about the schema and the above query, I need to point out:

- The event_page table is a union of monthly tables
- Joining the alias table twice is necessary because an alias may change during a session. aliases to personIDs are many to one. Hence the page view alias and session alias may be different but point to the same personID.
- All statistics are up to date (everything vacuum analyzed)!

As the explain below shows it appears that the Quick Sort is the bulk of my problem:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/6JjQ

In addition to that, there is a seq scan occurring (line 23 in the explain) on the session table yet that condition should be easily handled by the index.

I've run the same query on a different (albeit smaller) dataset and the query plan seems more sensible. This one executes in only 3 seconds. Here is the explanation:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/4k8t

Any ideas as to why the former explains chooses quick sort and the latter use HashAaggregate to achieve the DISTINCT?

What can I do to optimize the query and avoid quick sorting?

Why (in both cases) is the planner choosing a seq scan of the session when that filter is covered by an index?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you set enable_sort to off, what do you get for an execution plan on the slower query?

Comment: You can do the rollup for each monthly table only once after they do not change anymore.

Comment: If I'm correct, your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is effectively an `INNER JOIN`. I doubt this affects the performance, but it can affect maintainability, and others' ability to follow the query. Is it required that there be at least one row with a matching page view alias?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the flaw here,

> Hash Cond: (((event_page_2016_8.person_alias)::text = (a.alias)::text) AND ((event_page_2016_8.session_id)::text = (s.session_id)::text))

It thinks that condition returns 2 rows. Instead it returns 11,861,365. If it returned 2 rows, a quick sort almost certainly would have been faster. The question is primarily why does it think that it's so far off there..

You may want to try to refresh the statistics (or even raising the statistics target for those tables) with `ANALYZE event_page_2016_8 alias session`, or see what could be returning so many rows to begin with.

Also this conditional doesn't make much sense to me

```
join alias as A
  on (O.person_alias = A.alias)
left outer join session as S
  on (O.session_id = S.session_id) 
join alias as A1
  on ( A1.alias = S.person_alias and A.person_id = A1.person_id)
```

Maybe I'm missing something. So you're self-joining `A` to `A1` on `person_id` but also S.person_alias which has to share a session_id.. Why not just

```
join alias as A
  on (O.person_alias = A.alias)
join session as S
  USING (session_id)
```

And leave out `A1` entirely? You're not using it in the `SELECT` list?

Comment: Thanks Evan. So let's start with the Hash Join estimate you mentioned. 11M vs 2 is quite the discrepancy,  however - the second query plan link shows a similar issue `Hash Join (cost=211,345.82..393,431.24 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1,883.910..4,126.021 rows=801,151 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (((s.person_alias)::text = (a1.alias)::text) AND (a.person_id = a1.person_id))` see line 3 of the second explain link.

Comment: With regard to joining alias twice: It is necessary because alias is an intermediary table between event_page.person_alias and session.person_alias. It's not enough to simply join on session_id. This is simply a biproduct of how data is collected and stored and I have to live with it.

Comment: After looking into this I can say with confidence that the estimate vs actual row count mentioned above is a red herring. It looks as though that's how it shows append operation and the above is the product of the union all view